# Correct way to initialize boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, shared-ptr

I am just getting started to work with `boost::shared_ptr` so I have searched around and I see that there are several ways of initializing it:

```
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myclass = boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass());
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myclass = new MyClass();
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myclass = boost::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

And of assigning it:

```
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> someOtherType::getMyClass();

boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myclass = someOtherTypePointer->getMyClass();
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myclass = boost::make_shared<MyClass>(someOtherTypePointer->getMyClass());
```

Which one would be the preferred way for the init/assign and why?

Thank you.

Comment: You should correct the examples: `class` is a reserved keyword:

Comment: Your examples of assignment are not really assignments (it's copy initalizations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(1) boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> c(boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass()));
(2) boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> c(new MyClass());
(3) boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> c(boost::make_shared<MyClass>());
```

The first one is unnecessarily complex.

*(2)* and *(3)* seem similar but use `make_shared` whenever you can (i.e. when you don't need a custom deleter: [Are there any downsides with using make_shared to create a shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147600/are-there-any-downsides-with-using-make-shared-to-create-a-shared-ptr)).

`make_shared`:

- is more efficient. It usually allocates memory for `MyClass` object and for the `shared_ptr`'s control block with a single memory allocation. In contrast, *(2)* performs at least two memory allocations. So `make_shared` reduces allocation overhead, memory fragmentation and improves locality (see [GotW #89](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/) point 2)
- avoids explicit `new` (and, at least with C++11, it's more clear: `auto c(std::make_shared<MyClass>());`).

The main use of the assignment is when you want to copy a previously-existing `boost::shared_ptr`, to share ownership of the same object.

If you need to take ownership of a raw pointer you should use `reset` ([boost shared_ptr: difference between operator= and reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351823/boost-share-ptr-difference-between-operator-and-reset)).